# box size of my html form doesnt has the right size

Tags: html, css

So I have this html and css and I'm trying to build a form.
Everything is fine, except about the "Email" input box, which should be just below the "Name" input box, not on the same line.

Using the `"Inspect Element"` from the browser, I noticed the label tag for the name has `height=0px` and the next label(email) has `height=61px`. And the problem is related with these 2 labels. Could someone help me with this? I'm beginner with css and I would appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt:400,700|Lato:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body id="top">
<div id="cv" class="instaFade">


        <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

                var proceed = true;
                //simple validation at client's end
                //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
                $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
                    $(this).css('border-color',''); 
                    if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
                    }
                    //check invalid email
                    var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
                    if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                        $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                        proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
                    }   
                });

                if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
                {
                   //data to be sent to server         
                    var m_data = new FormData();    
                    m_data.append( 'user_name', $('input[name=name]').val());
                    m_data.append( 'user_email', $('input[name=email]').val());

                    //instead of $.post() we are using $.ajax()
                    //that's because $.ajax() has more options and flexibly.
                    $.ajax({
                      url: 'x',
                      data: m_data,
                      processData: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      type: 'POST',
                      dataType:'json',
                      success: function(response){
                         //load json data from server and output message     
                        if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                            output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }else{
                            output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                        }
                        $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
                      }
                    });


                }
            });

            //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
            $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
                $(this).css('border-color',''); 
                $("#result").slideUp();
            });
        });
        </script>

        <div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
            <div class="form-style-heading">test</div>
            <div id="contact_results"></div>
            <div id="contact_body">
                <label>
                    <span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Phone <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91"  required="true" class="tel-number-field"/>&mdash;
                    <input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
                </label>
                <label><span>Attachment</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file_attach" class="input-field" />
                </label>

                <label for="subject"><span>Regarding</span>
                    <select name="subject" class="select-field">
                        <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
                        <option value="Advertise">Advertisement</option>
                        <option value="Partnership">Partnership Oppertunity</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
                <label for="field5"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required="true"></textarea>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and my style.css

```
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,samp,small,strong,sub,sup,var,b,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video {
    border:0;
    font:inherit;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
    display:block;
}

html, body {background: #181818; font-family: 'Lato', helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #222;}

.clear {clear: both;}

p {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #444;
}

#cv {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.mainDetails {
    padding: 25px 35px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #cf8a05;
    background: #ededed;
}

#name h1 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}

#name h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-left: 2px;
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#mainArea {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

#headshot {
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

#headshot img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#name {
    float: left;
}

#contactDetails {
    float: right;
}

#contactDetails ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

#contactDetails ul li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: #444;
}

#contactDetails ul li a, a[href^=tel] {
    color: #444; 
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

#contactDetails ul li a:hover { 
    color: #cf8a05;
}


section {
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}

section:first-child {
    border-top: 0;
}

section:last-child {
    padding: 20px 0 10px;
}

.sectionTitle {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.sectionContent {
    float: right;
    width: 72.5%;
}

.sectionTitle h1 {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #cf8a05;
}

.sectionContent h2 {
    font-family: 'Rokkitt', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.subDetails {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.keySkills {
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-column-count:4;
    -webkit-column-count:4;
    column-count:4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #444;
}

.keySkills ul li {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 602px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    #headshot {
        display: none;
    }

    .keySkills {
        -moz-column-count:2;
        -webkit-column-count:2;
        column-count:2;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 601px) {
    #cv {
        width: 95%;
        margin: 10px auto;
        min-width: 280px;
    }

    #headshot {
        display: none;
    }

    #name, #contactDetails {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .sectionTitle, .sectionContent {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sectionTitle {
        margin-left: -2px;
        font-size: 1.25em;
    }

    .keySkills {
        -moz-column-count:2;
        -webkit-column-count:2;
        column-count:2;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mainDetails {
        padding: 15px 15px;
    }

    section {
        padding: 15px 0 0;
    }

    #mainArea {
        padding: 0 25px;
    }


    .keySkills {
        -moz-column-count:1;
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        column-count:1;
    }

    #name h1 {
        line-height: .8em;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
}

@media print {
    #cv {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes reset {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes reset {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes reset {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    40% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.instaFade {
    -webkit-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

    -moz-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

    animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.quickFade {
    -webkit-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

    -moz-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;

    animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.delayOne {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, .5s;
    animation-delay: 0, .5s;
}

.delayTwo {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, 1s;
    animation-delay: 0, 1s;
}

.delayThree {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, 1.5s;
    animation-delay: 0, 1.5s;
}

.delayFour {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 2s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, 2s;
    animation-delay: 0, 2s;
}

.delayFive {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 2.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, 2.5s;
    animation-delay: 0, 2.5s;
}

/* form style */
.form-style{
    max-width: 450px;
    padding: 40px 30px 40px 40px;
    font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.form-style-heading{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.form-style label{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.form-style label > span{
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.form-style span.required{
    color:red;
}
.form-style .tel-number-field{
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.form-style  .long{
    width: 120px;
}
.form-style input.input-field{
    width: 48%;
}

.form-style input.input-field,
.form-style .tel-number-field,
.form-style .textarea-field,
 .form-style .select-field{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #C2C2C2;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 7px;
    outline: none;
}
.form-style .input-field:focus,
.form-style .tel-number-field:focus,
.form-style .textarea-field:focus,  
.form-style .select-field:focus{
    border: 1px solid #0C0;
}
.form-style .textarea-field{
    height:100px;
    width: 55%;
}
.form-style input[type="button"],
.form-style input[type="submit"] {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f3f3f3;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f3f3f3;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f3f3f3;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form-style input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f3f3f3 5%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    background-color: #28739E;
}
.form-style .success{
    background: #D8FFC0;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2E6800;
    border-left: 3px solid #2E6800;
}
.form-style .error {
    background: #FFE8E8;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FF0000;
    border-left: 3px solid #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is `clear: both` because `.form-style label > span` has `float`

```
.form-style label {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/okvjmkpq/)**

**note:** nice form!